# LLVM static value analysis for optimization

Tags: compiler-construction, compilation, llvm, formal-methods, formal-verification

Let's say I have a function like this:

```
int foo(int a, int b, int d, int x){
  if (c) {a = 1; b = 1; d = a;}
  else {a = 2; b = 2; d = 1;}
  if (a == b) {x = d;} else {x = 0;}
  return x;
}
```

This trivial function returns always 1. Compiling with clang with -O2 option and looking at the disassembled code LLVM correctly compiles this function as `return 1;`.

My question is: How does llvm do static value analysys? weakest precondition techiniques? value propagation? Hoare's techniques?

Comment: llvm is open source. You can also look at a list of optimizations offered by the llvm optimization tool `opt` by looking at the available command line options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LLVM does all sorts of things: see [here](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html).

You can get a dump of the intermediate representation after each optimisation pass like this:

```
clang -c -mllvm -print-after-all -O2 foo.c
```

to identify which stage is doing what.

---

In fact, this particular example is not really very magical!

If you convert it to [SSA form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form), it looks something like this:

```
  // block 1
  if (c == 0) goto L1;
  // block 2
  a_0 = 1;
  b_0 = 1;
  d_0 = a_0;
  goto L2;
L1:
  // block 3
  a_1 = 2;
  b_1 = 2;
  d_1 = 1;
  goto L2;

L2:
  // block 4 (has two possible predecessors: block 2 or block 3)
  a_2 = PHI(a_0, a_1); // i.e. a_0 if we came from block 2, a_1 if we came from block 3
  b_2 = PHI(b_0, b_1); // i.e. b_0 if we came from block 2, b_1 if we came from block 3
  d_2 = PHI(d_0, d_1); // i.e. d_0 if we came from block 2, d_1 if we came from block 3
  if (a_2 != b_2) goto L3;
  // block 5
  x_0 = d_2;
  goto L4:
L3:
  // block 6
  x_1 = 0;
  goto L4;

L4:
  // block 7 (has two possible predecessors: block 5 or block 6)
  return PHI(x_0, x_1); // i.e. x_0 if we came from block 5, x_1 if we came from block 6
```

Simply propagation of constant values results in this:

```
  // block 1
  if (c == 0) goto L1;
  // block 2
  a_0 = 1;
  b_0 = 1;
  d_0 = 1;
  goto L2;
L1:
  // block 3
  a_1 = 2;
  b_1 = 2;
  d_1 = 1;
  goto L2;

L2:
  // block 4
  a_2 = PHI(1, 2); // i.e. 1 if we came from block 2, 2 if we came from block 3
  b_2 = PHI(1, 2); // i.e. 1 if we came from block 2, 2 if we came from block 3
  d_2 = 1;         // PHI(d_0, d_1) == PHI(1, 1) i.e. 1 regardless of where we came from
  if (a_2 != b_2) goto L3;
  // block 5
  x_0 = 1;  // (we've deduced that d_2 == 1 regardless of control flow)
  goto L4:
L3:
  // block 6
  x_1 = 0;
  goto L4;

L4:
  // block 7
  return PHI(1, 0); // i.e. 1 if we came from block 5, 0 if we came from block 6
```

Simplifying to remove the assignments which are no longer used for anything else gives this:

```
  // block 1
  if (c == 0) goto L1;
  // block 2
  goto L2;
L1:
  // block 3
  goto L2;

L2:
  // block 4
  a_2 = PHI(1, 2); // i.e. 1 if we came from block 2, 2 if we came from block 3
  b_2 = PHI(1, 2); // i.e. 1 if we came from block 2, 2 if we came from block 3
  if (a_2 != b_2) goto L3;
  // block 5
  goto L4:
L3:
  // block 6
  goto L4;

L4:
  // block 7
  return PHI(1, 0); // i.e. 1 if we came from block 5, 0 if we came from block 6
```

...and now the first conditional is clearly a no-op; and the second must always be true (the block 5 path) because `a_2` and `b_2` are the same expression.  So the result is

```
  return 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However I was trying to understand, apart from the example, if LLVM makes use of logical mathematical provers to infer assertions that are used to optimize the code, or all the optimizations are based more on value propagation and alias analysis rather than logical provers.

Comment: @GiacomoTagliabue Making use of automated theorem provers for compilation is an interesting research topic for the next ten years (if someone picks it up), but no existing compiler uses this approach.  See university professor John Regehr's opinion on the subject: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2012/03/29/Why-do-signed-overflows-so-often-do-what-programmers-expect#c119